# Can not use Playwright to login on JS?

Tags: javascript, testing, playwright

```
const { test, expect } = require('@playwright/test');
test.only('Login 1', async ({ page }) => {
  await page.goto('my login page');
  await page.fill('input[name="userId"]', 'my userId');
  await page.fill('input[name="password"]', 'my password');
  await page.locator('#idPasswordInputForm a.input_area_btn_01').click({timeout: 30000});
})
```

I use above code to test login on my page automatically. However, after it runs to this line: `await page.locator('#idPasswordInputForm a.input_area_btn_01').click({timeout: 30000});` on debug mode, It stuck on this step: `waiting for scheduled navigations to finish`.

Login on my page still works fine if I login manually.

Have I mistake something and how to fix it?

Comment: Can you share a reproducible version of the page, or the page itself, so the code can be run and experimented with? There's nothing obviously incorrect with the code taken in isolation--the issue is in the specific page's behavior that might force you to use a different coding strategy, but there's no telling what that might be. Using `.evaluate(el => el.click())` is a typical workaround for visibility.

Comment: Thank for your reply. This is the page to test: 'https://salonboard.com/login/'. You can random any userId and password to login. Because in my case, it stuck on `waiting for scheduled navigations to finish`.

Comment: Thanks, seems like some weird page-specific behavior where it simply doesn't navigate if you're in Playwright. It's probably detecting the robot using a trickier method than user agent. I'm not sure how to bypass this offhand.